# Count hits of a specific file with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have 3 files

1. index.html
2. stream.pls
3. counter.php

How can I show in counter.php the total hits of stream.pls?
I want to see how many times stream.pls is opened/loaded.

I tried this but that's not working:

```
<?php

define("COUNTER_START_VALUE", 0);
define("COUNTER_LOG", "stream.pls"); //name of file you want to use to save the counter value

/*************************************************************************************************/
function IncrementCounter() 
{   
   $create_file = !file_exists(COUNTER_LOG);

   if( !($fh = fopen(COUNTER_LOG, $create_file ? "x+b" : "r+b")) )
      return "Error";       
   //do an flock here, maybe, I don't know :-)

   //Reading current value of counter:
   if($create_file)
      $count = COUNTER_START_VALUE;
   else
   {
      $count = (int)fread($fh, 9); //reads 9 digits (supposing max 1 billion count)   
      rewind($fh);
   }

   //Writing new counter value:
   if(!fwrite($fh, ++$count))
      return "Error";
   if(!fclose($fh);)
      return "Error";       

   return str_pad($count, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

?>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling that function anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to display total number of visits to that file ,

Then don't be complicated , simply add variable named $counter as like you added it ,
and then increment it on every file open, or read ..

```
 if($create_file)
      $count = COUNTER_START_VALUE;
 else {
      fread($fh, 9);
      rewind($fh);
      $count++;
 }
```

or you can use same thing near fopen like ,

```
if( !($fh = fopen(COUNTER_LOG, $create_file ? "x+b" : "r+b")) )
      return "Error"; 
else
    $count++;
```

and better if you declare the $counter at start of this function

```
function IncrementCounter() 
{   
   $create_file = !file_exists(COUNTER_LOG);
   $counter = COUNTER_START_VALUE;
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

I hope this will solve your problem :) :) :)